# How can I integrate fabric digits login with polymer application?

Tags: polymer, twitter-digits

I am making an application which will use users phone number to log in. So I am using digits api. Now I have seen how to use its web login. But I am not able to integrate it in my polymer web application.

```
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">
    <script id="digits-sdk" src="https://cdn.digits.com/1/sdk.js" async></script>
</head>
```

I pasted script in head tag as mentioned.

```
<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'my-view1',
  properties:{
  textArea: {
  type: String,
  value: "this is text area",
  notify: true,
  reflectToAttribute: true
  }
  },
  attached: function(){
    console.log("Attached")
    this.$.Digits.init({ consumerKey: 'YOUR KEY HERE' })
    }

});
```

And one more doubt is that can i paste javascript script after Polymer({}); but under `<script>` tag? Will this create any problems. Or I have to write all my code under Polymer({});

Comment: Can you create a code snippet in plunkr or somewhere or paste some more code. This information does not seem enough to figure out your problem

Comment: Also I don't understand that last question :)